# Transistor UART voltage translator circuit are these NPN or PNP transistors?

Tags: transistors, uart

I am interfacing 1.8V and 3.3V UART lines, and due to one of the module's UART lines being a boot-config pin, it cannot be pulled up during the boot process. The module manufacture recommends the transistor circuit below for the logic level shifting.

I actually tried routing these lines through a 1.8 to 3.3V logic level shifter IC I already had on my PCB.  It is the second picture below, but with that set-up I had to cut the traces on the boot-config line just to get the module to boot properly.

But my question is with this transistor circuit, I wasn't given any other information but am assuming these are NPN transistors.  Is this correct, and are there any other major considerations I should take into account when laying out the pcb?

[image: recommended]
[image: failed]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transistors in those reference circuits are all NPN - the emitter arrows are Not Pointing iN.

On an PNP transistor, the emitter arrows are Pointing iN Proudly.

(and MOSFETs have totally different symbols)

Comment: Do you know what the NM over the capacitors is?

Comment: Probably "Not Mounted".  If making a PC board, place a footprint for them in case we need them.